# Убрать селектор из URL

Tags: php, html, select

Всех приветствую.

Есть форма:

```
<form action="example.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="example">
    <input type="submit" value="test">
    <select name="selector">
        <option value="0">Селектор</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>       
</form>
```

Так как идет GET-запрос, то все аргументы name идут в URL. (example.php?example=test&selector=1)

Как можно сделать так, чтобы данные передавались в файл example.php, но чтобы селектор не шел в URL?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Хренью друг страдаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как всегда есть 2 варианта реализации.

Описываю первый: Перед отправкой формы методом GET делаем поле selector закрытым т.е. disabled.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('form select[name=selector]').prop('disabled', true);
    return true;
});
```

если так не отработает код (не будет успевать закрыть Селект до отправки) то делаем вот так:

```
$('form input:submit').click(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form select[name=selector]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('form').submit();
    return true;
});
```

И второй способ - это до обрабатывать GET запрос на стороне сервера методом PHP.
Например вот так:

```
//удаляем не нужный параметр
if(isset($_GET['selector'])) {
    unset($_GET['selector']);
    // получаем строку вида key=val&key1=val1&key2=val2
    $clean_url = http_build_query($_GET);
    // остается сделать редирект любым удобным способом header('Location...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

method="post"

Comment: @mountpoint, к сожалению, мне нужен именно GET-метод.

Comment: post от get именно тем и отличается. вы можете конечно, передать данные с помшью js в кастомном заголовке...

Comment: @evansive, а почему post не подходит?

Comment: Что-что, простите? 
Я хочу чтобы селектор не отображался, но метод POST мне не подходит?
Из этой же серии:

 - Я хочу создавать объекты, но объектно-ориентированные языки не подходят.
 - Я хочу создать сайт, но программировать - не подходит.
 - Я хочу приготовить яичницу, но яйца не подходят.

Comment: золотые слова. лови плюс

Comment: А может человек хочет чтобы не было селектора, а был URL типа /home/news/123212 ?

Comment: не ответ, конвертирую

Comment: a может у него просто напросто не обробатывается _POST запрос такое как вариант может быть?

Comment: @jcmax, если не обрабатывается POST - это либо связка апача, мускула и пхп неправильно настроена, либо руки не из того места.

Answer (score 2):

Хм, если ничего не путаю, то можно через js сохранить в куки, а из php эти куки подхватить.?

Comment: Тоже думал такое написать, но потом постеснялся своей бредовой идеи :)